# Javascript viewport aspect ratio doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I have made a javascript `if` wrap who's purpose is to make the following nested code only work when aspect ratio is larger than 12/9 (1.33). It doesnt work tho.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//This is the apect ratio locker. 
            if ((window.screen.width / window.screen.height) >= 1.33) { 
//The nested code is only supposed to apply when aspect ratio is greater than 12/9
                $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > (window.screen.height / 100 * 41.7 - 70)) {
                        $('body').addClass('fix');
                    } else {
                        $('body').removeClass('fix');
                    }
                });
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    $("#logo-top").css("opacity", 1 - $(this).scrollTop() / (window.screen.height / 100 * 40));
                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: How you're testing this script?

Comment: All the functions work. The problem is that they are still in effect when viewport aspect ratio is smaller than 12/9.

Comment: Typo? `if ((window.screen.width / window.screen.height) >= 1, 33) {...`

Comment: Would it not be better to apply your your 'fix' using CSS and a media query? This would also have the advantage of re-evaluating after a screen resize.

Comment: The fix tag is to be applied once 'window' is scrolled a certain amount (41.7vh - 70px to be exact), but only when aspect ratio > 12/9.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make javascript update on aspect ratio change, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to fix your condition to:

```
if ((window.screen.width / window.screen.height) >= 1.33)
```